# Swift curl to 3rd party website not working unless I allow arbitrary domains

Tags: swift, http, https

My request looks as such

```
let headers = ["Host:" : "www.fortune500companysite.com", "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Connection" : "keep-alive", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1"]
        let request = formatRequest(url: "https://www.fortune500companysite.com/", method: "GET", headers: headers, dataString: nil)
```

I need help formatting my info.plist so that the request (and subdomain requests) works and the app is approvable by apple.

Sending the request off only works with:

```
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Which as we know, is a one way ticket to getting your app rejected by apple.  Without it, I get the following error:

```
nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9824]
error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004ea60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.fortune500companysite.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.fortune500companysite.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.})
```

This code I found in someone else's question doesn't help either

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fortune500companysite.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Is "TLSv1.2" given?

Comment: @shallowThought what do you mean, I don't understand most of this stuff just kind of hacking together what I can from the answers already on overflow

Comment: In this case I recommend to search for the error on SO.